# Press actionButton and go to another page on shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I tried triggering a button to migrate to another page of my app, but I can't do it in shinydashboard.

When I clicked on `btn1`, it should go to `page D` (`tabName = "four"`):

In the first application (**normal shiny**), it works because it's on the same page, but I would like to change the pages when clicking the `btn1` button in **shinydashboard shiny**).

I'd just like to click `btn1` (inside `Page 1 > B`) and switch pages.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

##################################normal shiny##################################
ui_1 <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(box(
    actionButton("btn1", "Go to Next Table", 
                 onclick = "location.href='#table2';"),
    tableOutput("tbl1")
  )),
  fluidRow(id = "table2", box(
    tableOutput("tbl2")
  ))
)

server_1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl1 <- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$tbl2 <- renderTable(mpg)
}

shinyApp(ui_1, server_1)

##################################shinydashboard shiny##################################
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(
      text = "Page 1",
      menuSubItem(text = "A", tabName = "one"), 
      menuSubItem(text = "B", tabName = "two")
    ), 
    menuItem(
      text = "Page 2", 
      menuSubItem(text = "C", tabName = "three"), 
      menuSubItem(text = "D", tabName = "four")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "one", titlePanel(title = "A")
    ), 
    tabItem(
      tabName = "two", titlePanel(title = "B"), 
      actionButton("btn1", "Go to Next Table", 
                   onclick = "location.href='#shiny-tab-four';")
    ), 
    tabItem(
      tabName = "three", titlePanel(title = "C")
    ), 
    tabItem(
      tabName = "four", titlePanel(title = "D")
    )
  )
)

ui_2 <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server_2 <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui_2, server_2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `updateTabItems` inside an observer to move around.  Try this

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu( id = "tabs",
    menuItem(
      text = "Page 1",
      menuSubItem(text = "A", tabName = "one"),
      menuSubItem(text = "B", tabName = "two")
    ),
    menuItem(
      text = "Page 2",
      menuSubItem(text = "C", tabName = "three"),
      menuSubItem(text = "D", tabName = "four")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "one", titlePanel(title = "A")
    ),
    tabItem(
      tabName = "two", titlePanel(title = "B"),
      actionButton("btn1", "Go to tab four" )#,
                   # onclick = "location.href='#shiny-tab-four';")
    ),
    tabItem(
      tabName = "three", titlePanel(title = "C")
    ),
    tabItem(
      tabName = "four", titlePanel(title = "D"),
      actionButton("btn2", "Go to tab one" )
    )
  )
)

ui_2 <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server_2 <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn1, {
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs","four")
  })
  observeEvent(input$btn2, {
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs","one")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui_2, server_2)
```